# What is the simplest method of programmatically adding data to JSON?

Tags: php, javascript, html, json

For a PHP/HTML page what is the simplest method of adding data to JSON?
Should I be using PHP, JS, or jQuery?

I've tried different lots of different methods found online, but I can't get any to work. I've tried all of these but I can't get it quite right.

```
 var myObject = new Object();
 JSON.stringify()
 JSON.parse()
 $.extend();
 .push()
 .concat()
```

I have this JSON file loaded

```
    {"commentobjects": 
        [
                {"thecomment": "abc"},
                {"thecomment": "def"},
                {"thecomment": "ghi"}
            ]
    }
```

I want to programmatically add

```
    var THISNEWCOMMENT = 'jkl;
    {"thecomment": THISNEWCOMMENT}
```

so that the JSON variable will be

```
    {"commentobjects": 
        [
                {"thecomment": "abc"},
                {"thecomment": "def"},
                {"thecomment": "ghi"},
            {"thecomment": "jkl"}
        ]
    }
```

///////////////////
Edit after answer
//////////////////

This is the ajax in my index.php file I used to call the PHP function (in its separate file):

```
    function commentSaveAction ()
    {
        var mytext = $(".mycommentinput").val();
        mytext = mytext.replace("\"","'");

            $.ajax({
                url: 'php/commentwrite.php',
                data: { thePhpData: mytext },
                success: function (response) {
               }
            });
    }
```

And this is the finished PHP function I used with the help of deceze:

```
    <?php

    function writeFunction () 
    {
        $filename = '../database/comments.txt';

        $arr = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename),true);
        $myData = $_GET['thePhpData'];  

        $arr['commentobjects'][] = array('thecomment' => $myData);
        $json = json_encode($arr);

        $fileWrite=fopen($filename,"w+");
        fwrite($fileWrite,$json);
        fclose($fileWrite);
    }
    writeFunction ();   

    ?>
```

//////////////////////
with JS and not PHP 
/////////////////////

```
        var myJsonData;

        function getCommentData ()
        {
            $.getJSON('database/comments.txt', function(data) {

                myJsonData = data;

                var count = data.commentobjects.length;
                for (i=0;i<count;i++) {
                    $(".commentbox ul").append("<li>"+data.commentobjects[i].thecomment+"</li>");
                }
            }); 
        }

        function commentSaveAction ()
        {
            var mytext = $(".mycommentinput").val();
            mytext = mytext.replace("\"","'");

            myJsonData.commentobjects.push({"thecomment": mytext});

            var count = myJsonData.commentobjects.length;
            $(".commentbox ul").append("<li>"+myJsonData.commentobjects[count-1].thecomment+"</li>");
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whichever language you do it in, you have to *parse* the JSON string into an object/array, modify it, then encode it back into a JSON string. Don't attempt any direct string manipulation of the JSON string. PHP example:

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
$arr['commentobjects'][] = array('thecomment' => 'jkl');
$json = json_encode($arr);
```

Whether to do this in Javascript or PHP or elsewhere depends on when/why/where you need to do this; that's impossible to say without knowing more about the use case.

Comment: you don't need to do anything if you're in javascript... that's the beuty of json, it's js-friendly!

Comment: @Ziarno If you receive the JSON string as string in JS from an AJAX call or so, you still need to parse it.

Comment: yes that's true, but jQuery automatically detects that it's json and does it for you. Also, there is nothing about ajax in the question.

Comment: @Ziarno Sure, just saying it's not all automagic in Javascript either. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with `json_encode` and `json_decode` PHP functions.

```
//work on arrays in php
$arr = array('sth1', 'sth2');

//here you have json
$jsonStr = json_encode($arr);

//array again
$arrAgain = json_decode($jsonStr);

$arrAgain[] = 'sth3';
//json again
$jsonAgain = json_encode($arrAgain)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do it in javascript:

```
var x = {"commentobjects": 
    [
            {"thecomment": "abc"},
            {"thecomment": "def"},
            {"thecomment": "ghi"}
    ]
};

x.commentobjects.push({"thecomment": "jkl"});
```

Comment: Your answer works great. Using just a variable works well. I was using an object and it was giving me (object Object) problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
var THISNEWCOMMENT = 'jkl',
    myObj = JSON.parse(rawJson),
    newComment = {"thecomment": THISNEWCOMMENT};
myObj.commentobjects.push(newComment);
var serialized = JSON.stringify(myObj);
//send the updated JSON to your controller
```

Parse the object, access the `commentobject` list inside of it, push the new comment in the list and then serialize the updated object again.